# Instead of opening a shell, it just ends

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, execve

I was trying to write an assembly program (NASM on 64 bit Ubuntu 20.04 machine) that executes syscall execve of the sh command.

**Instead of opening a shell, it just ends.**

I would really appreciate any help in resolving this.

Here is the code:

```
global _start
_start:

mov rax,59

xor rdi, rdi
mov rdi, str1

xor rsi, rsi
mov rsi, str2

mov rdx, 0xa

syscall     ;execute execve syscall

mov rax,60
xor rdi,rdi
syscall     ;execute exit syscall

section .data
str1: db '/bin/sh'  ;string of the first argument of execve 
str2: db '/bin/sh',0xa  ;string array of the secand argument of execve.
```

I compile and execute the asm file like this:

```
nasm -felf64 execve_sh.nasm -o xxx.o    
ld xxx.o -o zzz         
./zzz
```

Thanks a lot
Tali

Comment: Although not your only problem, your strings need to be nul(0) terminated. I recommend using a debugger and most especially `strace` to see the parameters to the execve system call. You'd likely discover the issues. `strace ./zzz`

Comment: I tried to add 0xa to str1, but didn’t change a thing. 
Str2 is terminated with 0xa.

Comment: They have to be terminated with nul (0x0), not with a newline (0xa).

Comment: But also think carefully about how the argument vector looks.  It's not a pointer to a string, it's a pointer to an array of pointers.  You will have to construct such an array in memory, with a null pointer marking its end.

Comment: Just a note, the "just ends" is presumably because the execve system call fails, and "just ending" is what your program deliberately does (by invoking the `_exit` syscall) if the `execve` syscall returns.  You would get more information if you would inspect the error code left in `rax` by the `execve` system call; it is the negative of an `errno` value.

Comment: Terminated strings with nul (thanks Nate Eldredge) fixed the problem of the first input of execve, as being watched through strace ./zzz (thanks Michael Petch).
I realize that instead of setting a pointer (address) to array of pointers to strings for the second argument of execve, I set pointer to array of strings, instead.